# Prebid.js - Run multiple auctions one after another

Tags: javascript, prebid.js, prebid

I have been trying to setup multiple auctions to run on a single Prebid.js instance or multiple instances.
I have already attempted to run an auction normally after one had ended however it never sends the command through, I have also tried renaming the entire library to something custom which had also failed.

My question is, if something like this is even possible and how I would go about doing it?

Comment: What command are you using to run the auction after the other ends? Prebid supports multiple concurrent auctions so I don't see why this wouldn't work. Can you provide code of your page or a link to the page where you are trying this so we can troubleshoot?

Comment: I successfully do concurrent auctions, the issue occurs when trying to make an auction after at least 1 other auction ends

Comment: Will need to see your dev environment to give you any more help.

Comment: Wouldn’t recommend this since it can lead to missed bids—prebid clears out the adids between auctions. You should look at the events to schedule a second auction... or just add more bids into the first auction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further testing and messing around with it, we have somewhat solved the issue in a very hacky way. What we decided to do was create a friendly iframe and put our version of prebid into that iframe from there we put our script into the iframe as well which interacts with the webpage outside of the iframe. It's a very hacky way of doing it but it seems to work.